# jQuery Cycle animation doesn't work

Tags: jquery, cycle

I would like to use jQuery Cycle Plugin to animate logos from sponsors in my sidebar on [this site](http://www.sc-hoersching.at)

I have tried different html markups and js code variations to call the cycle-function, but I can't get it working.

Is the .js file loaded in the wrong place? Anything wrong with the markup?

Any help is much appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there was a conflict between some scripts there are used on that page. I found a solution though by recreating the problem:
First, you used `$(".sponsoren")` which is wrong, because `sponsoren` is an id. So it should have been `$("#sponsoren")`.

Second, you should place the script location and the script itself on the bottom of the page. After doing so, it still didn't work for me, so I got rid of the `$(document).ready(function(){});` part, since it wasn't necessary anymore. I ended up with the following code:

```
<script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.cycle.all.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery('#sponsoren').cycle({
        fx: 'scrollDown'
    });
</script>
```

Remember, I placed this on the bottom of the page, and this seemed to work. This might not be the best solution, but it works this way.

Comment: Working fine now. Thanks a million! :D